# How to get values other from a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using the stuff function to get a list of ids. But there are some values that are duplicate:

```
----------
3180,3181,3182,3180,4180
----------
3183,3184,3184,4181
```

I just want to get the list of ids that are not duplicated, desired results:

```
----------
3181,3182,4180
----------
3183,4181
```

This my query:

```
    SELECT oa.AssetId,
       oal.AssetLineId,
      SNIds = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(isn1.Id AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                     FROM dbo.InventoryOperation o1
                         INNER JOIN dbo.InventoryOperationAsset oa1 ON oa1.OperationId = o1.OperationId
                         INNER JOIN dbo.InventoryOperationAssetLine oal1 ON oal1.OperationAssetId = oa1.OperationAssetId
                         INNER JOIN dbo.InventoryOperationAssetLineSerialNumber ioalsn1 ON ioalsn1.OperationAssetLineId = oal1.OperationAssetLineId
                         INNER JOIN dbo.InventorySerialNumber isn1 ON isn1.Id = ioalsn1.SerialId
                     WHERE oa.AssetId = oa1.AssetId AND oal.AssetLineId = oal1.AssetLineId
                 FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'')
FROM dbo.InventoryOperation o
    INNER JOIN dbo.InventoryOperationAsset oa ON oa.OperationId = o.OperationId
    INNER JOIN dbo.InventoryOperationAssetLine oal ON oal.OperationAssetId = oa.OperationAssetId
    INNER JOIN dbo.InventoryOperationAssetLineSerialNumber ioalsn ON ioalsn.OperationAssetLineId = oal.OperationAssetLineId
GROUP BY oa.AssetId, oal.AssetLineId;
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks in advance if anyone could help.

Comment: can you share your query?

Comment: please accept my answer and vote up :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
SELECT DISTINCT columns FROM table;
```

That makes sure you only get non duplicates.

Comment: this query would get all unique ids (only one instance) and not exclude ones that have duplicates. It will get 3180 and 3184 also which are not part of desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Query that provides data to STUFF function should use following query to get only unique ids (e.g. `3181,3182,4180,3183,4181`) and not the ones that have duplicates (e.g. `3180,3184`)

```
  SELECT column_name
  FROM TABLE_NAME
  GROUP BY column_name
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Updating answer with `STUFF` function sample ...

```
SELECT STUFF(', ' + REPLACE((SELECT id + ', ' AS 'data()'
FROM stackoverflow
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
FOR XML PATH('')), '', ''), 1, 2, '')
```

Sample Run
[image]

Comment: But I need to use the stuff function to return the list of ids?

Comment: can you share your query?

Comment: I have added my query

Comment: check my updated answer, if you want to delete the last comma then you can use `reverse` function with stuff and take care of deleting the last comma.

Comment: thank you very much @JRG, Your query has processed exactly as I expected :)